# tvOS Programmatically changing focus of one UITableViewCell to another

Tags: uitableview, swift4, tvos

i have a tvOS application where in im using custom tableview cells, lets say i have 3 tableviewcells.
Now i need to make programmatically update the focus from one cell to another cell.
i tried using the `func selectRow(at indexPath: IndexPath?, animated: Bool, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition)` where it doesnt select that cell(as the focus is still on the previous cell not on the one i desired)
It scrolls to particular cell but doesnt change the focus

So is there any way in i can make the focus to programmatically move from one tableview cell to another?

My TableviewStucture is like below

- First Cell: Normal TableviewCell)
- Second Cell: UICollectionView inside a TableviewCell
- Third Cell: Normal TableView Cell

I have the cell reference of destination cell to reach.

- I need to make focus change from first cell to third cell,
- or change focus from second cell to third cell,
  In case of second cell have a call back which gets called and have the index of the
  particular cell too (`cellForRow(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell?`).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this can be solved using the `indexPathForPreferredFocusedView`
Which worked fine for me.
Sorry for trouble..

Comment: You can answer your own question and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be solved with using `indexPathForPreferredFocusedView`, which works just fine.